# Can't locate MozRepl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the MozRepl module)

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl, www-mechanize-firefox, mozrepl

I am trying to logon to a website which has Javascript Login using Mechanize Firefox. The program works fine on Ubuntu, but when I run on windows I am getting the following error.

```
Can't locate MozRepl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the MozRepl module) (@I
NC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at login-firefox.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at login-firefox.pl line 3.
```

I am running the program on Windows 7 64 bit, and using Active Perl.

I have installed the following modules using cpan & Have run the tests of Mechanize Firefox, the results were successful.

- MozRepl
- MozRepl::RemoteObject
- WWW::Mechanize::Firefox

Comment: Are they installed in one of the `@INC` directories? If not, you'll need to set `PERL5LIB` to a suitable value.

Comment: Hi @triplee I have added PERL5LIB in Environment variables of Computer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to tackle the issue!!!

If you are installing modules via Command Prompt, Run the Command Prompt as Administrator.

If you are installing modules via PPM, Open PPM.bat as Administrator.